# Applying context through method but not through constructors

Tags: android, android-context

I was reading about `context` in `Android` and were using in my android application.But then a thought came into my mind. That , Why do we pass  `context` in the  `constructor` only and not some `method`,something like that `component.setContext(context)`,where `component` is a hypothetical component and `setContext` is a hypothetical method and context could be `getConetxt/this/getApplicationContext`(upon the requirements).

if anyone thinks that title or anything is not appropriate,they are free to change/edit.

Please help me to understand it.Thanks

Comment: downvoters,please explain the reason of down voting,so that I can improve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically both are same, if you pass a `Context` via constructor or via any setter method.

You will **still have to have a reference to the Context** in your class which will either be initialized during the creation of the object, that is via the constructor or will be initialized later via any setter method.

In both the cases, the Context reference is still there. It is just a question about **eager initialization** or **lazy initialization**.

But in case of eager initialization, while accessing the Context in the class you are sure that the context has been initialized for sure and you can safely use it.

But there is no guarantee for that in case of lazy initialization. And as a size note do check out the difference about the two types of Context - **Application context** and **Activity context**.

Comment: Nice thought, but still waiting for some technical reason(if any).

Comment: It is not just a thought. Have tried to explain you technically as well. Its a very simple Java problem, you might just be a bit confused with it. Let me know if you need to know any thing more.